# Subscription removal susceptible to CSRF attacks?

Tags: bug, profile-page, security

It seems to me that the [subscriptions tab](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=subscriptions) in the profile settings page is susceptible to CSRF attacks since the links to remove yourself from subscriptions are just plain html links. Please correct if I am wrong or CSRF is the wrong terminology for this.

I tried copying one of the links to remove a subscription to a new tab and it actually unsubscribed me.

Would it be possible to change this to update via POST, optionally with a CSRF token to prevent CSRF attacks?

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't look great. Kind-of silly and pointless to abuse, but better to do it right.